Spring Boot Jar cannot find auto config files
I have a fairly simple Spring Boot app. One yaml file with spring gateway configurations, and then one file with the main Application class and the main function.
I build the jar file as follows:
./gradlew clean bootJar -x test

It gets built without problems.
The build.gradle.kts file looks like this:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.example.reverseproxy.ReverseProxyApplicationKt")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.3"

dependencies {
    /* kotlin co-routines */
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")

    /* kotlin reflection */
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    /* spring web */
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")

    /* spring cloud gateway */
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    /* test - dependencies */
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")

//    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
//    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
//    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}


tasks.withType<Test> {
    enabled = false
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<Jar> {

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.reverseproxy.ReverseProxyApplicationKt"
    }

    archiveBaseName.set("ReverseProxy")
    archiveVersion.set("0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")

    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

    // Include dependencies in the JAR file
    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get()
            .filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }
            .map { zipTree(it) }
    })

    // exclude specific signed files from being included in the final JAR
    exclude("META-INF/*.SF")
    exclude("META-INF/*.DSA")
    exclude("META-INF/*.RSA")
}

tasks.named("bootJar") {
    dependsOn("jar")
}
tasks.named("bootJar") {
    mustRunAfter("jar")
}
tasks.named("bootDistZip") {
    dependsOn("jar")
}
tasks.named("bootDistZip") {
    mustRunAfter("jar")
}
tasks.named("bootDistTar") {
    dependsOn("jar")
}
tasks.named("bootDistTar") {
    mustRunAfter("jar")
}
tasks.named("startScripts") {
    dependsOn("bootJar")
}
tasks.named("startScripts") {
    mustRunAfter("bootJar")
}

However, when I run this
java -jar build/libs/ReverseProxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I keep getting:
19:35:51.003 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpClientSslConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration$NettyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpClientSslConfigurer' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
19:35:51.006 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'httpClientSslConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration$NettyConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'httpClientSslConfigurer' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}


Where am I going wrong?
Repo (Minimum Reproducible Example):
https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF/ReverseProxy
Update
The below did not help. What can I try next?
// ensure that both compiled classes and resources are included in the JAR file
from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
sourceSets.main.configure {
    resources.srcDirs("src/main").includes.addAll(arrayOf("**/*.*"))
}

Update 2
If I comment this out from the gradle file,
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")

It works. Only problem is that since this is a reverse proxy, it's a dependency I very much need.

Hi your repository is too big to clone can you add minimal reproducible sample, also please dont add different combination of dependencies for compilation, unknown exception may begin to pop up, add dependency for file where classes are missing.

I don't think you need to clone the whole repo. Just the reverse proxy folder, you can download. I didn't understand your 2nd comment.

The "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties' available" message is indicating that the ServerProperties @ConfigurationProperties bean has not been created. For reactive applications, it is usually created by ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.
Looking at the sample you provided, the problem appears to be caused by your unusual build.gradle.kts file.
Usually to check why auto-configuration hasn't been applied. I would run with -Ddebug, however, your jar is incorrectly packages so this doesn't work.
If you run unzip -l build/libs/ReverseProxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with your current application you'll see that it contains both .class files and .jar from Spring. This is the root cause of your problem.
To fix it, you can delete src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and simplify you build.gradle.kts file to the following:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2023.0.3"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

With these changes the jar looks normal and will run.

Hi Steve, thank you. Here is my entire Repo: https://github.com/dreamstar-enterprises/docs/tree/master/Spring%20BFF/ReverseProxy . I will try running -Ddebug later today.

Wow - that's INCREDIBLY HELPFUL - it worked like a charm!

You are not including resources in the jar.
Only including main source set -
from(sourceSets.main.get().output)

Refer this
Add files to Gradle sourceSets in Kotlin DSL

It didn't work for me. See update above
